# redirect www to non-www (CNAME needed?)

Tags: dns, 301-redirect, no-www, cname

I want to redirect `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com`.

I would like to avoid duplicated content. Is 301 redirect in nginx sufficent? Is it needed for me to add a CNAME record? My concern is that CNAME record may affect my SEO.

I see that this question has been asked here before, but there was no mention on whether 301 redirect is sufficient without CNAME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 301 redirect in nginx will suffice. You can also specify your [preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en).

Answer (score 3):

To implement a redirect, your `www` subdomain must resolve to a web server that issues a redirect to your non-www domain.  It doesn't matter whether you use `A` records or `CNAME` records to make that happen.

A DNS `CNAME` is not a redirect.  It just says that the IP address resolves to the same IP address as some other host name.   Because of this using a `CNAME` is neither necessary nor sufficient to implement a redirect.  To implement a redirect you need to:

1. Configure a web server to receive requests for a domain name.  The web server examines the headers of the request which contain the `Host:` header.   The host header contains the domain name of the request.  The web server issues a `301 Permanent Redirect` response with a `Location:` header containing the redirect URL.
2. Configure DNS for the domain to point to that server.  Either `A` records that specify the IP address of the server, or a `CNAME` record that specifies an alternate host name for the server may be used.

A `CNAME` records won't hurt SEO if you do use it.   It is very common for websites with good SEO to be configured with either `A` or `CNAME` records.  Choose whichever your host recommends.  The only caveat is that a `CNAME` record is not allowed to be used for the bare (non-www or `@`) record.   If you try to do so your website may not work reliably and any email you have coming to your domain will not be delivered correctly.  `CNAME` records work fine for subdomains though.